# What's the difference between a murder and an assassination?

Tags: differences

I am unsure what the technical difference is between a murder and an assassination. Instinctively I feel it's to do with the victim - perhaps their fame? Royalty?

What is the distinction between the two?

Comment: We need to show background effort. Include in the question what the dictionary says about each.

Comment: Looking up both words in a dictionary quite clearly shows the difference between the two words.  Assassination is a type of murder, usually by a paid killer and done secretively.  The target is often of a higher profile, though not necessarily.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, assassination is used to refer to a known person, often a political figure.

[Assassination:](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassination)

> Assassination is the murder of a prominent person or political figure by a surprise attack, usually for payment or political reasons.

[Murder](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Murder):

> The unlawful killing of one human by another, especially with premeditated malice.

The difference in meaning comes from the origin of the word, 
[assassin](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=assassin&searchmode=none) (n.)

> 1530s (in Anglo-Latin from mid-13c.), via French and Italian, from Arabic hashishiyyin "hashish-users," plural of hashishiyy, from hashish (q.v.). A fanatical Ismaili Muslim sect of the time of the Crusades, under leadership of the "Old Man of the Mountains" (translates Arabic shaik-al-jibal, name applied to Hasan ibu-al-Sabbah), *with a reputation for murdering opposing leaders after intoxicating themselves by eating hashish. The plural suffix -in was mistaken in Europe for part of the word (compare Bedouin).*

Comment: BTW: in Spanish "asesinato" is simply "murder"

Comment: I don't know why _payment reasons_ would be included. I would not call a murder for hire, or a killing over money, to be an assassination. In popular usage, anyway, an assassination is killing some public person for ideological or political reason, whether by professional or amateur. John F Kennedy was assassinated; John Lennon was murdered.

Comment: @PhilPerry: I suspect that payment is mentioned because of the (mostly fictional) notion of an assassin for hire taking on high-profile targets. The Jackal attempted to assassinate de Gaulle for reasons of payment. Of course the people who hired him did so for political reasons. A murderer for hire might be merely a "hitman", though...

Comment: There are plenty of murders committed for pay (e.g., Mob hitmen), and an assassination can be by a loner (think Lee Harvey Oswald [probably]). I don't think payment should enter into the discussion at all - it merely muddies the water. A killing can be made by someone for hire, but it's who the target is (and for what reason) that defines if it's considered a murder or an assassination.

Answer (score 5):

An assassination is the targeted killing of a specific pre-arranged person. It is especially used in cases where the target was a prominent public figure, and when the motive was political or ideological, but is not restricted to either.

*Murder* has been used to cover various deliberate acts of killing that were considered dishonourable or unjust in various ways, which has had various legal definitions over the course of history (e.g. it was once only applicable to a secretive killing, but saying "everyone saw, and he was awake and facing me" will not mean you only have to pay a fine today!)

As a legal term the precise definition varies according to jurisdiction, but generally includes a degree of premeditation, and a lack of justification (such as self-defence or act of war). Note that the premeditation may not necessarily be of the killing itself; e.g. in many places if you kill someone in the course of a premeditated armed crime, it is considered murder, though you did not intend to kill when you planned the crime. In general use, it remains a term applied to any killing that the speaker condemns.

As such, many assassinations are murders, and vice versa, but not all murders are assassinations (a bombing intended to cause terror, or the killing of a security guard who happened to be the guard on duty is not an assassination), and not all assassinations are necessarily murder (the targeted lawful killing of a specific combatant during war) and some are debated (whether the above case should be allowed by the rules of war is debated, and whether something was an act of war or of terror might also be).

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, the dictionary definitions suggest that "assassination" is usually associated with a well-known victim. But I think there's a clearer way to distinguish how the two are used in common parlance:

**"Assasination" is almost exclusively reserved for murders in which someone is being killed primarily *due to their title or role* in an organization or movement.**

Most typically, it's because they are the head of the entity in question (like a head of state, or the leader of an uprising), but not necessarily.